# EnvelopeID Changed after correction?

Tags: soap, docusignapi

I have 2 signature document and the first signer already signed. The document is still in process. So I went to correct the second signer. I realised the envelopeID changed after the correction.

What will it happen to the old envelope? Voided?

```
function getDocuments($pdfbytes) {
    $documents = array();
    $id = 1;


        $d = new Document();
        $d->PDFBytes = $pdfbytes;
        $d->Name = "Demo Document";
        $d->ID = $id++;;
        $d->FileExtension = "pdf";
        array_push($documents, $d);


    return $documents;
}

function buildEnvelope($pdfbytes) {
    $envelope = new Envelope();
    $envelope->Subject = $_SESSION["Taskmaster"];
    $envelope->EmailBlurb = "Please Sign by logining ";

    $envelope->AccountId = $_SESSION["AccountID"];
    $envelope->Recipients = constructRecipients();
    $envelope->Tabs = addTabs(count($envelope->Recipients));
    $envelope = processOptions($envelope);
    $envelope->Documents = getDocuments($pdfbytes);
    return $envelope;
}

function constructRecipients() {
    $recipients = array();



        $r = new Recipient();

        $r->UserName =$_SESSION["Secretaryname"];
        $r->Email =  $_SESSION["Secretaryemail"];
        $r->RequireIDLookup = false;


        $r->ID = 1;
        $r->Type = RecipientTypeCode::Signer;
        $r->RoutingOrder = "2";

       // if(!isset($_POST['RecipientInviteToggle'][$i])){
            $r->CaptiveInfo = new RecipientCaptiveInfo();
            $r->CaptiveInfo->ClientUserId = 2;
            $r->CaptiveInfo->embeddedRecipientStartURL=SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN;
       // }

        array_push($recipients, $r);


    if(empty($recipients)){
        $_SESSION["errorMessage"] = "You must include at least 1 Recipient";
        //header("Location: error.php");
        exit;
    }

    return $recipients;
}

function sendNow($envelope) {
    $api = getAPI();



    $csParams = new CreateAndSendEnvelope();
    $csParams->Envelope = $envelope;
    //print_r($csParams);
    try {
        $status = $api->CreateAndSendEnvelope($csParams)->CreateAndSendEnvelopeResult;
        //echo "Result for Create and Send <br>";
        //print_r($status);

        if ($status->Status == EnvelopeStatusCode::Sent) {
            addEnvelopeID($status->EnvelopeID);
            $correct = new Correction;

    $correct->EnvelopeID = $status->EnvelopeID;
    $correct->RecipientCorrections = addRecipientCorrection();
    $correctparams = new CorrectAndResendEnvelope();
    $correctparams->Correction  = $correct;

    //print_r($correctparams);
   //Send
   $response = $api->CorrectAndResendEnvelope($correctparams);
   //print_r($response);
//exit;
$_SESSION["EnvelopeID"]=null;
$_SESSION["Direct"]="Yes";
            header("Location: getstatusanddocs.php?envelopid=" . $status->EnvelopeID . 
                "&accountID=" . $envelope->AccountId . "&source=Document");
        }
    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
      $_SESSION["errorMessage"] = $e;
      header("Location: error.php");
    }
}

function addRecipientCorrection(){
$correction = new RecipientCorrection();

$correction->PreviousUserName = "xxxxxx";
$correction->PreviousEmail = "xxxxxxx";
$correction->PreviousSignerName = $correction->PreviousUserName;
$correction->PreviousRoutingOrder = "2";
$correction->CorrectedUserName = $_SESSION["Secretaryname"];
$correction->CorrectedEmail    = $_SESSION["Secretaryemail"];
$correction->CorrectedSignerName = $correction->CorrectedUserName;

return $correction;
}

//========================================================================
// Main
//========================================================================
loginCheck();

if($_SESSION["Taskmaster"]=="xxxxx"){
$api = getAPI();
$RequestPDFParam = new RequestPDF();
$RequestPDFParam->EnvelopeID = $_SESSION["EnvelopeID"];
$result = $api->RequestPDF($RequestPDFParam);
$envPDF = $result->RequestPDFResult;
//file_put_contents("./Cert/".$_SESSION["EnvelopeID"].".pdf", $envPDF->PDFBytes);
//echo "Stop here";
//exit;


    $envelope = buildEnvelope($envPDF->PDFBytes);

    sendNow($envelope);

}else{
echo "You have no power";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it was envelopeID that changed and not recipientID? Correcting an envelope should not change the envelopeID IMO. Any snippets or pseudo code you can share may help too.

Comment: To Luis' point, there is no way that an envelopeId can change (cloning makes a copy and creates a new envelopeId). More info here would help to see what is going on.

Comment: I used the pdfbyte to load the document for the envelope. Is that a bad approach?

Comment: Update with my codes

Comment: I gave your code a once-over.. Here is what i would recommend high level: add document, add recipients, send out envelope. You only need to perform a correction if it turns out that a recipients email@ was incorrect/bounced, or if you realize you need to send it to a different recipient. It looks to me like you are doing a CORRECT as part of your mainstream flow, which seems unnecessary. An envelopeID can only be created once an envelope is SENT or created in a DRAFT state. I do not see any DRAFT logic here. Feel free to share an example of before/after envelopeID's in the comments.

Comment: The previous envelope is SENT status. This is the correction module. So should I use create envelope and send envelope in draft state for this?

Comment: add document, add recipients and send out envelope, isn't this the normal flow of an envelope? How do I make a correction module? I read the SOAP API guide but I am confused at the document addition for correction module. Please help

Answer (score 0):

EnvelopeId does not change after correction. The envelopeID never changes. New envelopes can be created, but the original GUID that was used will keep living in the system.